# Do tasks continue running after an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

A simple question:

Running multiple threads/Tasks(C#), in any thread (whether it be the UI thread or a background thread), do the other threads continue running or are they all stopped immediately(read: as soon as possible) when an exception is thrown?

Comment: By stop running, do you mean the threads exit? Why do you think they would stop running?

Comment: My definition of "stop" being: the thread exits (gracefully or not).

Comment: Check out results of this search - [.net unhandled exception policy](http://www.bing.com/search?q=.net+unhandled+exception+policy), in particular http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is one foreground thread running, say the UI thread. And there are multiple background threads running. If there is an exception in the foreground thread and its execution stops, then the process will get stopped and all background threads will get stopped irrespective of their state.
But if an exception is thrown in a background thread, it will not propagate to the main thread, and main thread wont be stopped from execution.So the answer to your question lies in which thread throws the exception.